# Finding birth details of grandfather born Malta in 1900

Tags: birth-records, 1900s-decade, malta

How do I find the birth details of my grandfather-Frank George Cassar born Malta in 1900, including his birth certificate?

His father was George Cassar.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  You will probably find it helpful to review our [Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help), and in particular [ask].

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I think your question has been downvoted because it contains more than  one question which goes against our focussed Q&A format.  I think you should use the [edit] button beneath your question to remove the question about his father.  That can be asked as a new question.  For both questions be sure to tell us not only what you are looking for but where you have already looked.

Comment: I've removed your second question so that answerers can focus on the first.  If you wish to also ask about your great grandfather George Cassar's birth and marriage certificates then please do that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This Maltese Government website explains how to obtain these documents:

https://certifikati.gov.mt/en/Home